# Web2py linked tables error with Field type

Tags: python, mysql, web2py, linked-tables

I am trying to link two mysql tables in web2py which have a column with identical entries (different rows though). I want to display the first table in a grid and have a link that displays the appropriate entries of the second table. So far this is what i have:

```
in models --> db.py

    db.define_table('total_ec_numbers',
    Field('id','integer', label=T('ID')),
    Field('query_name','string', label=T('Gene ID')),
    Field('hit_name','string', label=T('Hit name')),
    Field('hit_accession','string', label=T('Hit accession')),
    Field('ec','string', label=T('EC number')),
    Field('hsp_evalue','string', label=T('E-value')),
    Field('hsp_length','string', label=T('HSP length')),
    Field('hsp_percent','string', label=T('HSP percent')),
    Field('sample','string', label=T('Sample')),
    Field('extra','string', label=T('Extra info')),
    migrate=False, format = '%(query_name)s')

    db.total_ec_numbers._singular = "EC numbers results"
    db.total_ec_numbers._plural = "EC numbers results"


#--------
    db.define_table('total_genes',
    Field('id','integer', label=T('id')),
    Field('gene_id','string', label=T('Contig')),
    Field('gene_name','string', label=T('Gene name')),
    Field('sequence','text', label=T('Sequence')),
    Field('seq_length','integer', label=T('Sequence length')),
    Field('description', 'reference total_ec_numbers', label=T('Gene ID')),
    Field('sample','string', label=T('Sample')),
    Field('extra','string', label=T('Extra info')),
    migrate=False)

    db.total_genes._singular = "All sequences"
    db.total_genes._plural = "All sequences" 


in controllers --> default.py


    important_columns=[db.total_ec_numbers.query_name,db.total_ec_numbers.hit_name,db.total_genes.description]

    form2=SQLFORM.smartgrid(hotzyme_tests.total_ec_numbers, linked_tables=['total_genes'], create=False, fields=important_columns, deletable=False, editable=False, maxtextlength=64, paginate=10)
```

with this i get a nice grid of the "total_ec_numbers" table with the link "all sequences" next to each entry. But when i click on the link i get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1_start=553_stop=756_strand=+'


The fields that have the identical entries are the db.total_ec_numbers.query_name and the db.total_genes.description and they have string data values. Nevertheless web2py seems to search for integers. Do you know how i can change that? Thank you in advance,
```

Comment: Do you have the ability to change the structure and contents of these tables, or is this a legacy database in use with other systems? Note, reference fields are intended to store the integer record ID's of the referenced records, not copies of string fields from referenced records. Also, you should not name a field "id", as web2py creates its own auto-incrementing integer "id" field to serve as a primary key.

Comment: I have full access to the database yes. I only recently found out about the reference field storing the record id and then i realised why it didn't work. I only created an id field as i wanted to use the web2py scripts (that work with legacy databases) to generate the db.py automatically for all of my tables but i can change that. Is there another way to do this link with the fields? maybe the "left" attribute of the sqlform.grid?